# SystemTray is not displayed with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, tomcat, processbuilder, system-tray

I have two Java applications:

1) A web application running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.
2) A console application running in background. In this application I use a SystemTray icon to notify the users that the application is running. I used a program to turn this jar into a .exe. The exe runs the jar.

I want to start the console app every time that someone access the web app. To accomplish this I used ProcessBuilder.

The console application works fine in the following scenarios:

- When executed from Eclipse;
- When executed from a runnable jar;
- When the web app is launched from Eclipse.

When I run the web application directly with Apache Tomcat, the SystemTray of the console application is not displayed. The console application works fine but the icon is not created.

Here is the code of the ProcessBuilder used on the web app:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Core\\core.exe");
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\Core"));
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the code of the console application, where i create the SystemTray:

```
SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
Image image = new ImageIcon("img/tray-on.png").getImage();
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu();

MenuItem itemStart = new MenuItem("Start");
itemStart.setEnabled(false);
itemStart.addActionListener(listenerStart);
MenuItem itemStop = new MenuItem("Stop");
itemStop.addActionListener(listenerStop);
MenuItem itemLog = new MenuItem("Log");
itemLog.addActionListener(listenerLog);
MenuItem itemClose = new MenuItem("Close");
itemClose.addActionListener(listenerClose);
popupMenu.add(itemStart);
popupMenu.add(itemStop);
popupMenu.add(itemLog);
popupMenu.add(itemClose);

trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Core is Running");
trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popupMenu);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

try {
    systemTray.add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    logger.fatal(ex.getMessage());
}
Launcher.getInstance().start();
```

Edit:

[image: The System Tray and Task Manager]

Thanks guys. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `new ImageIcon("img/tray-on.png")` assumes there is an `img` directory relative to the current directory.  Since your ProcessBuilder sets the current directory of the child process to C:\Core, the ImageIcon constructor expects to find C:\Core\img\tray-on.png.  Verify that a file is present at that location.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, the file is present.

Comment: The process may block if it is trying to print to standard output or standard error.  Try adding `processBuilder.inheritIO();` or `processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);`.

Comment: I tried both and got the same retults. I added a picture in my post. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @VGR you ended hours of debugging for me by suggesting processBuilder.inheritIO();